# Customise JWT auth-token generation using user_id and otp as input

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a system that uses 'mobile_number' and 'otp' for login.
For the purpose I have create the first api that accept the mobile number and returns the user details. Otp generation and sending is done in the sane api.

I want to create the togen-generation api, and the api accepts 'user_id' and 'otp'.

Models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
  dial_code_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  is_resource = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "my_user"

  def __str__(self):
    return self.mobile_number


class Otp(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  otp = models.IntegerField()
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

  class Meta:
    db_table = "otp"
```

I have done the Token generation using https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

but the below endpoint,

```
path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

it accepts username and password for token generation.

I am a beginner to django-rest and I want your help for the customisation.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this, I'll go with the most obvious solution first.

Override `TokenObtainPairView` to replace the serializer with your own.

```
# in serializers.py
class MyAuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(
        label=_("Username"),
        write_only=True
    )
    otp = serializers.CharField(
        label=_("OTP"),
        write_only=True
    )
    token = serializers.CharField(
        label=_("Token"),
        read_only=True
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user_id = attrs.get('user_id')
        otp = attrs.get('otp')

        if user_id and otp:

            validated_otp = Otp.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, otp=otp).select_related("user").first()

            if not validated_otp:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "user_id" and "otp".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = validated_otp.user
        return attrs

# in views.py
class MyObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = MyAuthTokenSerializer


# in urls.py
path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

The second solution and the one I prefer is overriding the authentication mechinsm.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class OtpBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            # this is the only change from the model backend
            is_valid_otp = user.otps.filter(otp=password).exists()
            if is_valid_otp and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

and then in your settings add

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.your.OtpBackend']
```

This way instead of using the password for authentication it will use the OTP.

Also, keep in mind it's best to have validity on OTPs. They're meant to be one time only

Comment: I want to generate 'access_token' and 'refresh token' for the api. How can i do that in the same?

Comment: The second approach should do this automatically with the existing `TokenObtainPairView` as it works by authenticating the user. Only thing is for the user name you need to give the user id and for the password you need to give the OTP